# What's the difference between master data and dimension data

Tags: database, data-analysis, data-warehouse, olap, dimensional-modeling

I am kind of confused with the difference between master data and dimension  data. Both of them are said to be relatively stable data, eg, organization information, employee information, producti information， compared with transactional data，such as order.

I would ask what't the difference betweeen master data and dimension data, I think that most dimension table are from master data when doing data analysis?

Thanks

Comment: Some many websites and resources comprehensively studied them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Master data is a classification of the type of data.

Dimensional data is a classification of the way of organising/structuring data